# Dynamically serving users from one of the multiple servers behind a single domain?

Tags: php, apache, networking, dns, load-balancing

When someone registers to my SaaS app they are assigned to a region (US/EU/Pacific), and it is saved into the DB. In this example I have 3 servers, 1 for each region.

When a user logs in (it could be a single central server/subdomain for the whole world), I want to get their region from DB, and serve them from that server directly (so I do not just want to make a load balancer, I actually want the traffic to go directly to the assigned server).

Handling it using Round Robin on the DNS level is not a viable solution, because the servers in different regions will have different database content, and possibly different software versions, so random distribution is unwanted.

Obviously I could make different subdomains like us.app.com and eu.app.com, but what I would like to do is to solve this problem with a minimum number of subdomains.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need either a geo IP capable or latency based DNS service (e.g. AWS Route 53) to make shure visitors from a distinct region connect to the right server. See  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html if it's an option for you to use Route53.